# Getting the lowest value in while loop php

Tags: php, loops, variables, while-loop

I have this issue. It should be pretty easy but I am stumped and I have looked but I haven't found an answer. I will try to make it as descriptive as possible. This is a diminutive of my code:

```
<?php
   $myArray = [$a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f];
   $arrayLength = count($myArray);
      
   $i = 0; 
   while ($i < $arrayLength)
   {
       //Code that displays lowest value in array;
       //echo $myArray[$i] ."<br />";
       $i++;
   }
?>
```

My question is this:
Assuming, `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d`, `$e`, `$f` are user-entered variables and are all integers, how do I echo out the lowest value in the array in this while loop?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "lowest value of `$start`"? It's just the original value.

Comment: If you are using mysql why not use a `where` with `between`?

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: Please rephrase this question, it makes no sense.

Comment: If what you mean is the lowest of two user inputs use [min](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php). likewise [max](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) for the largest.

Comment: if you're *reducing* an array of values to a single result, then you use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) .. https://3v4l.org/WcUoZ (or min/max in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Save the original value of `$start` in another variable so you can echo it in the loop.

```
$lowest_start = $start;
while ($start <= $stop){
   echo "$lowest_start $start<br>\n";
   $start++;
}
```

We also usually use `for` loops rather than `while` loops:

```
for ($i = $start; $i <= $stop; $i++) {
    echo "$start $i<br>\n";
}
```